# Maybe a question of the Mean-value theorem of the Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, laplace-transform

$\phi(x)$ is bounded on $I_n=[\xi-\epsilon_n,\xi+\epsilon_n]$ and $\phi(\xi)\neq0$ ,where $\phi$ is continue at $\xi$, and $\epsilon_n=o(1)$ .
$h(x)\in C^2$ is continous ,and $\xi$ is the only maximum point of $h(x)$.

**How does this come** ?:
$$\int_{I_n}\phi(x)e^{n(h(x)-h(\xi))}dx$$

$$=(1+o(1))\phi(\xi)\int_{I_n}e^{n(h(x)-h(\xi))}dx$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M_n=\max_{I_n} \phi(x)$ and $m_n=\min_{I_n} \phi(x)$.
Then for the integral
$$  m_n \int_{I_n} e^{n(h(x)-h(\xi))} dx \leq \int_{I_n} \phi(x) e^{n(h(x)-h(\xi)} dx 
\leq M_n \int_{I_n} e^{n(h(x)-h(\xi))} dx $$
and 
$$ m_n\int_{I_n} e^{n(h(x)-h(\xi))} dx \leq \phi(\xi) \int_{I_n}  e^{n(h(x)-h(\xi)} dx 
\le M_n \int_{I_n} e^{n(h(x)-h(\xi))} dx $$
but since  $(M_n-m_n)= \phi(\xi)+o(1)$ due to the continuity of $\phi$,
we get  it.

Comment: Wow , really nice! Thank you very much !

Comment: @Alexander Lau accept the answer, please.

Comment: How do you know that $\Phi$ is integrable?

Comment: @ Michael Hoppe in the question it is assumed that the integral exists.